# How to get the list text from an class object having string and list in python

Tags: python, list, object

i got a question about how to get the list text from an class object having string and list in python.

I try to use str() to get the string value from the list, but it just shows me the empty string and the reference of the list.

```
Here is my class:

class ContentTranslation(object):
def __init__(self, language):
    self.language = language
    self.contentTranslationList=[]

def addContentTranslation(self, contentTranslation):
    self.contentTranslationList = contentTranslation

def getLanguage(self):
    return self.language

def getContentTranslation(self):
    return self.contentTranslationList


for j in range(1,noOfSessions):
    aContentList.append("a")
contentTranslation = ContentTranslation(language)
contentTranslation.addContentTranslation(aContentList)
listOfTranslationContent.append(ContentTranslation(contentTranslation))

for i in range(len(listOfTranslationContent)):
  print(str(listOfTranslationContent[i].getLanguage()))
  print(str(listOfTranslationContent[i].getContentTranslation()))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first `for` loop, you are passing an object to the constructor. Like so:

```
listOfTranslationContent.append(ContentTranslation(contentTranslation))
```

Instead change the body of first loop to this:

```
for j in range(1,noOfSessions):
    aContentList.append("a")

    # create object
    contentTranslation = ContentTranslation(language)
    contentTranslation.addContentTranslation(aContentList)

    # append to list
    listOfTranslationContent.append(contentTranslation)
```

Comment: even i change the range, it still returns the reference to me, but not the text

Comment: Check the updated answer.